# Can't transcribe with Mozilla DeepSpeech - Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, mozilla-deepspeech

I tried to install and run Mozilla DeepSpeech according to the guidelines shown in the official repo https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/blob/master/README.rst

But whenever I try to transcribe an audio sample with

```
deepspeech --model deepspeech-0.6.0-models/output_graph.pbmm --lm deepspeech-0.6.0-models.lm.binary --trie deepspeech-0.6.0-models/trie --audio audio/2830-3980-0043.wav
```

I get an `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` without any further explanation

Does anybody have any suggestions? What could be the possible reasons for this message?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of `tensorflow` do you have? (`pip list`) –  possibly related: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17411

Comment: @JRajan there are no tracebacks for system errors like that (unless you attach `gdb` or another debugger)

Comment: `tensorflow 2.0.0`. I installed it with Conda

Comment: What architecture, operating system and processor model are you running on? Judging by "illegal instruction", it's possible the Tensorflow library is using instructions your CPU doesn't support.

Comment: @AKX Ubuntu 18.04. My Intel Xeon X5650 does not support AVX/AVX2
See this thread https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/cant-transcribe-illegal-instruction-core-dumped/51925
Will post it as an answer today